# Add additional feature to CountVectorizer matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am stuck at a problem where I have to add an additional feature (average word length) to a list of token counts created by CountVectorizer function of scikit learn. Say I have the following code:

```
#list of tweets
texts = [(list of tweets)]

#list of average word length of every tweet
average_lengths = word_length(tweets)

#tokenizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1,1))
x_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(texts)
```

The format should be (tokens, average word length) for every instance. My initial idea was to simply concatenate the two lists using the zip-function like this:

```
x = zip(x_counts, average_lengths)
```

but then I get an error when I try to fit my model:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you solve it ?! could u post the sol. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own transformer like in [this](http://michelleful.github.io/code-blog/2015/06/20/pipelines/) article which give you average word length of every tweet and use [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html):

```
vectorizer = FeatureUnion([
        ('cv', CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1,1))),
        ('av_len', AverageLenVectizer(...))
    ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Because CountVectorizer returns a sparse matrix, you need to perform sparse matrix operations on it. You can do so by using `hstack` from `scipy.sparse`.

For example (taken from scipy's documentation):

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, hstack
A = coo_matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B = coo_matrix([[5], [6]])
hstack([A,B]).toarray()
array([[1, 2, 5],
   [3, 4, 6]])
```